# Ansible parse debug output

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I have this ansible output got from 3 different hosts, using ansible debug module:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.240.22.44] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": true,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "/opt/confluent/bin/nodefirmware smm1",
                "delta": "0:00:00.128325",
                "end": "2020-02-05 11:22:19.435049",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "/opt/confluent/bin/nodefirmware smm1",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "stdin": null,
                        "warn": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "10.240.18.20",
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2020-02-05 11:22:19.306724",
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "smm1: SMM: 1.10 (TESM14F)\nsmm1: PSOC: 0.7",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "smm1: SMM: 1.10 (TESM14F)",
                    "smm1: PSOC: 0.7"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": true,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "/opt/confluent/bin/nodefirmware smm1",
                "delta": "0:00:00.096292",
                "end": "2020-02-05 11:22:22.847949",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "/opt/confluent/bin/nodefirmware smm1",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "stdin": null,
                        "warn": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "10.240.19.21",
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2020-02-05 11:22:22.751657",
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "smm1: SMM: 1.10 (TESM14F)\nsmm1: PSOC: 0.7",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "smm1: SMM: 1.10 (TESM14F)",
                    "smm1: PSOC: 0.7"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to parse this output and display in the end, for each hosts, strictly the:

```
"stdout_lines": [
                    "smm1: SMM: 1.10 (TESM14F)",
                    "smm1: PSOC: 0.7"
```

The playbook that shows the above output is this:

```
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ smm_output }}"
     when: "('primary' in default_hostname or 'Primary' in default_hostname)"
     tags: ['ic', 'smm']
```

I tried with "{{ smm_output.stdout_lines }}" but says there's not such dict object

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering the output of a looping task. Quoting the documentation:

> When you register a variable in a task with a loop, the registered variable contains a value for each item in the loop. The data structure placed in the variable during the loop will contain a results attribute, that is a list of all responses from the module. For a more in-depth example of how this works, see the Loops section on using register with a loop.

To debug each `stdout_lines` of your respective `results` in `smm_output` you can use the following task:

```
    - name: debug result
      debug:
        var: item.stdout_lines
      loop: "{{ smm_output.results }}"
```

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables